# Nokogiri help without spaces

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

i have the following code:

```
#/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'cora'
require 'eat'
#require 'timeout'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://mobile.bahn.de/bin/mobil/bhftafel.exe/dox?input=Richard-Strauss-Stra%DFe%2C+M%FCnchen%23625127&date=27.01.12&time=20%3A41&productsFilter=1111111111000000&REQTrain_name=&maxJourneys=10&start=Suchen&boardType=Abfahrt&ao=yes"))
doc = doc.xpath('//div').each do |node|
  puts node.content
end
```

How can i remove the p-tags and spaces?

Comment: Can you explain more? I don't see any `<p>` in the output of your code. Do you mean that if there's a `<p>` inside a `<div>` you don't want to see the contents? And what spaces do you want to remove? All of them? Just blank lines?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guess at what you might want:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://mobile.bahn.de/bin/mobil/bhftafel.exe/dox?input=Richard-Strauss-Stra%DFe%2C+M%FCnchen%23625127&date=27.01.12&time=20%3A41&productsFilter=1111111111000000&REQTrain_name=&maxJourneys=10&start=Suchen&boardType=Abfahrt&ao=yes"))
doc.xpath('//div//p').remove
doc = doc.xpath('//div').each do |node|
  text = node.text.gsub(/\n([ \t]*\n)+/,"\n").gsub(/^\s+|\s+$/,'')
  puts text unless text.empty?
end
```

This removes all `<p>` elements from the document and then removes all blank lines and leading and trailing whitespace from the text. In the end, it does not print the text if the result was an empty string.

**Edit**: To make a variable for the date, wrap the above in a function and use string interpolation to construct your URL. For example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
def get_data( date )
  date_string = date.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
  url = "http://mobilde.bahn.de/…more…#{date_string}…more…"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  # more code from above
end
```

Comment: looks great...but can i make a variabel for the date? that he also search for the date right now?

Comment: @MARKUSM I've updated the answer to show this. In the future, please make another question, or include this in your original requirements. It's frustrating when a "question" slowly morphs and changes what's needed for a good answer.